# Preencher Serie xls com POI java

Tags: java

Tenho um código dentro de um for que ele pega uma determinada coluna e  inseri o valor, e atribui as quantidades de linhas definidas no for, por exemplo rows =1 ; rows<=10, coloco o setCellValue("10/02/2012") então ele preenche todos campo com esta mesma data, como faço para preencher em serie, onde vai encrementando.

```
for(int rowIndex = 1;rowIndex<=10;rowIndex++)
{

    Row rowsx = sheetAlunos.createRow(rowIndex);
    HSSFRow row = sheetAlunos.getRow(rowIndex);

    Cell data = row.createCell(0);
    data.setCellValue("10/02/2012");

}
```

Comment: Pode colocar o que você já fez?

Comment: adicionado codigo, no caso cada lop  do for ele tem que auto incrementar essa data definida inicialmente, igual no execel com a opção preencher serie.

Comment: Beleza, vc quer adicionar a data em série? ex: 10/02/2012, 11/02/2012.. ?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos lá, se entendi bem você quer pegar um data e incrementar 1 dia a cada vez que passar no laço, ex:

```
10/02/2012
11/02/2012
12/02/2012
```

Pra isso você pode usar a `Classe` [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) para adicionar dias em uma data, ex:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

No seu caso você precisa que esse numero de dias seja incrementado de acordo com sue laço. Você pode criar um método para fazer a conversão da data e atribuir os dias:

```
public String stringToCalendar(String date, int i) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(sdf.parse(date));
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i);
        return sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

Esse método recebe dois parâmetros, o primeiro é a data que você deseja passar que no caso é `"10/02/2012"` e o seguindo será o `rowIndex` para incrementa-lo na data.

O seu Laço ficaria dessa forma:

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= 10; rowIndex++) {
        //Chama o método que converte uma String pra Calendar e incrementa o rowIndex na data
        String date = stringToCalendar("10/02/2012", rowIndex);
        Row rowsx = sheet1.createRow(rowIndex);
        HSSFRow rowx = sheet1.getRow(rowIndex);
        Cell data = rowx.createCell(0);
        //Passa a string que foi retornada para a celula
        data.setCellValue(date);
}
```

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Extamente o que queria, conhecia a classe calendar porem nao tinha pensado em ultilzar ela